# Inputs break 100% width with no padding or border

Tags: html, css

## Issue

I'm creating a registration form that has inputs that are either `50%` or `100%` of the parent's `width`.

Inputs at `50%` need to be next to each other on the same line.

I want them to have padding and a border, however **no matter what I do** (even completely removing the padding, margins and border in CSS), **they always overspill 100% and result in the inputs going onto multiple lines**.

## Code

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1280px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper.c-640 {
  max-width: 640px;
}
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
input.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
input.w-50 {
  width: 50%;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 6px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 1px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  /* Just for testing and demonstration purposes */
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper c-640">
  <form id="register">
    <input class="w-50" type="text" name="name1" placeholder="First Name*" required>
    <input class="w-50" type="text" name="name2" placeholder="Last Name*" required>
    <input class="w-100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address*" required>
    <input class="w-50" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password*" required>
    <input class="w-50" type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Confirm Password*" required>
    <input class="w-100" type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the space between inline-block elements. Either remove the spaces or let object float:

```
float: left;
```

More info: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Removed spaces - worked great, will accept when I can.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing to add float rule to your inputs:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
    float: left;
}
```

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5n47mst/)

Comment: I have `display: inline-block` which means that, so long as they'll fit within 100%, they will be shown next to each other. The space between the elements were the issue!